# IIS SMTP used to relay Contact Us form messages to Gmail has been blacklisted by Google

Tags: dns, smtp, google-apps, spf, dkim

I have 2 Windows 2008 R2 boxes running in Microsoft Azure. My ASP.NET 4.0 site (let's imagine it's running at "example.com") has a standard Contact Us form.

When a user sends a Contact Us message, I use `System.Net.Mail` and `SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network` to deliver mail to an IIS6 SMTP server running on each box, which sends the mail to a Google Apps "enquiries@example.com" account, using the email address the user entered into the Contact Us form as the "From" address.

This was working beautifully for a year until I checked it today, and found this error in a .BDP file in the \Badmail folder:

> 550-5.7.1 Our system has detected an unusual rate of unsolicited mail originating from your IP address. To protect our users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has been blocked. Please visit http://www.google.com/mail/help/bulk_mail.html to review our Bulk Email Senders Guidelines.

Obviously Google upped their anti-spam strategies in the last 6 months - last time it worked was Feb 2013 (yeah, we don't get much mail luckily... yet).

I've read the Bulk Senders Guidelines linked above, but they're not really suited to my use case.  My case is not sending emails from our server to users of our site (I simply use the Gmail API and send from our enquiries@example.com for that), but rather to collect users' enquiries so that we can easily respond by clicking Reply in that inbox.

I am looking for the easiest solution here.  In response to the ones in Google's Bulk Senders Guidelines:

1. Use a consistent IP address to send bulk mail: I already do, doesn't seem to help
2. Reverse DNS:  Godaddy, my domain and DNS provider doesn't seem to support them: http://support.godaddy.com/groups/domains-management-and-services/forum/topic/how-do-i-setup-reverse-dns/  Anyone know if there's a way?
3. Use the same address in the 'From:' header on every bulk mail you send: This is totally not my use case. I'll have different From headers in every email
4. SPF record: I think this only works if I am sending From ...@example.com every time. Is that right? My feeling is SPF doesn't help me here. Would love someone to enlighten me.
5. DKIM: This looks hellishly complicated, but I'll pursue it if someone thinks it can work in this case. Specifically is it OK that the From address doesn't match the "signing domain"? Anyone got any good "how to" links?  And will this be sufficient for Google to un-blacklist me?
6. Sendgrid: Azure's preferred mail sending app. This means signing up, code changes, testing, and unknowns like "does Sendgrid allow any From address?  It's non-trivial, and I'd like to avoid this, but again, will go there if it's what people think is the sanest option.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please help me understand

Comment: Likely, the reason is that this isn't a code related question with a code based answer, and is somewhat open ended. However, _I_ feel it fits SO's guidelines.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be more careful with that next time.  Maybe ServerFault is better then?

Comment: Perhaps, although, sometimes it can be a crapshoot as to what people feel does/doesn't belong where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general answer to your questions, sending email on behalf of many different domains from one IP (e.g. example.net, example.org, and ex.co from 10.0.0.1) is generally seen as spammy behavior (and therefor not recommended).

Your points 1-5 only apply if you're sending from one domain. `rDNS`, `SPF`, and `DKIM` only improve delivery for one IP to one domain (in a *generally* 1:1) relationship.

Generally, the best way to avoid getting marked as spam in a situation like this is to set the `From` email as a consistent one that you actually control (e.g. enquery-sender@example.com), and then setting the `Reply-To` as the entered address (e.g. enquirer@someprovider.com). This way you consistently send from one domain, while still getting the benefit of replies going to the message originator (for example LinkedIn does it this way). Doing this will allow you to setup `rDNS`, `SPF`, and `DKIM` with benefit.

---

That said, if you decide that you don't want to use the recommended `Reply-To` method, you can use SendGrid to send from any arbitrary domain. It *should not* require any significant code change (just switching your current [SMTP credentials to SendGrid's](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/index.html#-SMTP)).

***Disclaimer:** I am a SendGrid employee.*

Comment: of COURSE Reply-To! Why didn't I think of that! Thanks!  But you know what, in the course of trying to work out further how to create SPR and rDNS (godaddy wizard is cryptic for mine), I signed up for sendgrid. Goodness me, how easy.  I'm a convert.  Thanks for the nudge in that direction!  Disclaimer: I don't work for SendGrid.

Comment: Incidentally, I found the C# System.Net.Mail code example on the SendGrid site just before your answer - very grateful for this a it saves me from messing around with NuGet and code re-write as you say. Thanks again!

Comment: So glad to hear it. I'm happy we could help.